# How do i encrypt password in three layers , SHA1, base64 encode and salt

Tags: java, base64, sha1, salt, password-encryption

I want to encrypt and decrypt password with high security .
First, the string password with be converted to SHA1 , then i also want to add base64 encode and lastly add SALT to it.

Is this doable in java?

I have sample code to encode in base64 and sha1 but i am not sure how to combine them all.

Here is snippet:

```
    String password = "password";
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    encryptedPassword = encoder.encode(password.getBytes());
```

Using SHA1:

```
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    md.reset();
    md.update(password.getBytes());
    System.out.println(new String(md.digest()));
```

Please suggest .

Comment: base64 has nothing to do with security. Salt is nothing more than a string you append to the plaintext before encryption, and compare with after decryption.

Comment: i recommend reading this site about hashing, especially the "The RIGHT Way: How to Hash Properly" part https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: You don't really seem to understand what SHA1 and salting is. It's not an encryption algorithm, but a hashing algorithm. And decrypting a hashed password is thus impossible: that's the whole point. Also, salting must be done BEFORE hashing, otherwise it doesn't have any purpose. So the process is 1. generate a random salt; 2. concatenate salt and password; 3. hash the result of the concatenation; 4. base64-encode the resulting byte array to get a printable string. 5. store the string and the salt in the database.

Comment: Ohh ok .... yes i have just started reading it out now. You are right. @JB

Comment: Note that SHA1 is now considered too weak to safely store passwords. You should use PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 or bcrypt. Both will deal with the salting for you.

Comment: Can you show up some link or sample code for similar? It will be easy for me to understand

Comment: I can see bcrypt implementation to be easy. As above you have suggested i think i can go ahead an try to use it.

Comment: One more point regarding password hashes -  always store passwords hash instead of password itself.

Comment: Yes it always better to store hash and compare hash with hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the things you have to think of when playing around with salts:

> 1. Generate a long random salt using a CSPRNG.
> 2. Prepend the salt to the
>      password and hash it with a standard cryptographic hash function
>      such as SHA256.

You need to append your generated Salt (generated with a **Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator**) to the password and then hash it with SHA-1.

Since SHA-1 is a hash Algorithm, you can't decode it. If you need to encrypt the password, you may read something about [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) or [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA)

I suggest you reading this article, [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), especially the part **The RIGHT Way: How to Hash Properly**, if you still want to hash your password properly.

Comment: Yes now i understand all logic of hash after reading it. Thanks for pointing out basics. 
+1 for your answer. This will surely help someone